# Python: defining new functions on the fly using "with"

Tags: python, with-statement

I want to convert the following code:

```
...
urls = [many urls]
links = []
funcs = []
for url in urls:
   func = getFunc(url, links)
   funcs.append(func)
...

def getFunc(url, links):
   def func():
      page = open(url)
      link = searchForLink(page)
      links.append(link)
   return func
```

into the much more convenient code:

```
urls = [many urls]
links = []
funcs = []
for url in urls:
   <STATEMENT>(funcs):
        page = open(url)
        link = searchForLink(page)
        links.append(link)
```

I was hoping to do this with the `with` statement. As I commented bellow, I was hoping to achieve:

```
def __enter__():
    def func():

..code in the for loop..

def __exit__():
  funcs.append(func)
```

Of course this doesn't work.

List comprehensions is not good for cases were the action `searchForLink` is not just one function but many functions. It would turn into an extremely unreadable code. For example even this would be problematic with list comprehensions:

```
for url in urls:
  page = open(url)
  link1 = searchForLink(page)
  link2 = searchForLink(page)
  actionOnLink(link1)
  actionOnLink(link2)
  .... many more of these actions...
  links.append(link1)
```

Comment: First of all: Why do you want to pass around functions? Yes, there *is* usecases for that, but they aren't that common. And second of all, why would you *not* use a function? There's nothing wrong with functions. :)

Comment: In case you got lost (like I did) this is a question to which the answer is:  use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit unconventional, but you can have a decorator register the func and bind any loop variables as default arguments:

```
urls = [many urls]
links = []
funcs = []

for url in urls:
    @funcs.append
    def func(url=url):
        page = open(url)
        link = searchForLink(page)
        links.append(link)
```

Comment: "Unconvential", to say the least. Still, eerily beautiful ;)

Comment: I think that the function `func` with get over-ridden every time. So I'll only get left with the last one ie the function that takes care of the last url. Won't I?

Comment: +1: This is really clever! @Guy: default arguments are evaluated at definition time, so the binding is Ok.

Answer (score 6):

It makes no sense to use `with` here. Instead use a list comprehension:

```
funcs = [getFunc(url, links) for url in urls]
```

Comment: This will call the function, he wants to return function objects.

Comment: I don't want to use the function `getFunc()`. That's the point

Comment: I love how spoiled people get after they start learning Python.  You have to write that as a separate function?! GASP

Answer (score 2):

Lose the line `<STATEMENT>(funcs):`

Edit:

I mean:  why would you do this?  Why define a new function for each page?  Why not just do this?

```
urls = [many urls]
links = []
for url in urls:
    page = open(url)
    link = searchForLink(page)
    links.append(link)
```

Comment: c'mon man.. it's just an example. Of course you can do your suggestion but it's not my question.

Comment: Meh. I voted +1, then though "hang on a minute" and unvoted, and now I decided to vote +1, and I can't. This is really the only answer that makes any sense so far.

Comment: @Guy: Yes it does. It tells you how to rewrite the code in a way that doesn't include that extra function call that you didn't want to have.

Comment: Sure it does.  The only thing you actually ask is "Ideas?"  This is a good one.  It's cleaner than your working example, and it doesn't have functions that modify variables that aren't passed into the function.  If there's something you're looking for that this doesn't do, please state what it is clearly in your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two ways to create functions: `def` and `lambda`. Lambdas are meant for tiny functions, so they may not be very appropriate for your case. However, if you really want to, you can enclose two lambdas within each other:

```
urls = [many urls]
links = []
funcs = [(lambda x:
            lambda:
              links.append(searchForLink(open(x))))(u)
         for u in urls]
```

A little too LISPish for my taste.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "with" to do this (even though, given that it's Python, you almost certainly could, using some bizarre side-effect and Python's dynamicism).

The purpose of "with" in Python is, [as described in the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), "to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by a context manager. This allows common try...except...finally usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse."

I think you're confusing Python's "with" with the [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/With)/[VisualBasic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(VS.80).aspx) "with", which may be cosmetically similar but which is effectively unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Good old [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import imap
links.extend(imap(searchForLink, imap(open, urls)))
```

Although, maybe you'd prefer [functional](http://oakwinter.com/code/functional/).

```
from functional import *
funcs = [partial(compose(compose(links.append, searchForLink), open), url) for url in urls]
for func in funcs: func()
```

I don't think it's worthwhile creating a class for `with` use: it's more work to create `__enter__` and `__exit__` than it is to just write a helper function.

Comment: that's pretty crazy. The best answer yet - thanks. 
I think I do understand what `with` does. I was hoping to stick `def func():` in the `__enter__` and `funcs.append(func)` in the `__exit__`. But, obviously, it won't be that easy.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better using generators to achieve the delayed computation you're after.

```
def MakeLinks(urls):
    for url in urls:
        page = open(url)
        link = searchForLink(page)
        yield link

links = MakeLinks(urls)
```

When you want the links:

```
for link in links:
    print link
```

The urls will be looked up during this loop, and not all at once (which it looks like you're tring to avoid).